# Memory allocator macro explaination

Tags: c, macros, malloc

I was trying to understand the code for memory allocator that implements malloc and I stumbled upon this macro

```
// get the size of the block from header
#define GET_SIZE(p)  (GET(p) & ~0x7)
```

The comment makes it clear what it does, but I can't understand what it does or how it is working. Can someone explain this in detail?

Comment: It extracts everything except  the 3 rightmost binary digits of the value returned by get(p). Roughly get(p) % 8 done faster.

Comment: @ArifBurhan So what exactly does ~0x7 does? I mean what's the logic for returning the 3 rightmost digits?

Comment: @ArifBurhan "done faster" - if you are using a 1970s compiler perhaps

Comment: @ArifBurhan No, they are _not_ the same. With `for (x = 0;;++x)`: `x & ~0x7` produces [0 repeated 8 times], [8 repeated 8 times], [16 repeated 8 times], 24 repeated 8 times], ... but `x % 8` is [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], ... You may have missed the `~`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In binary,  `0x7` is `.... 0000 0111`, and `~0x7` is `.... 1111 1000`, so the value of `GET(p) & ~0x7` is `GET(p)` "masking out" its three right-most bits, that is, setting them to zero.

For example, if `GET(p)` yields 10, which is `.... 0000 1010`, `GET_SIZE(p)` will be `8`, which has a binary representation of `.... 0000 1000`.

This is just similar to `GET(p) - GET(p) % 8`, but `GET(p)` is evaluated once in this case. If `GET_SIZE(p)` is defined as `GET(p) - GET(p) % 8`, something like `GET_SIZE(i++)` will cause undefined behaviour. Also, it might have some effect on performance, but modern compilers are believed to be clever enough to do optimisations like this.

Comment: ~7 means inverting 7 in a bitwise way, and the & has the function of a     bit-mask, letting through some, and stopping others.

Comment: Thanks! The example made it much more understandable!

Comment: Most of these include files were written in the seventies and never re-written, to prevent new errors creeping in.